# cannot open mysql

Tags: mysql

I have an urgent problem:

I could not find /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock anymore. my mysql server can not run. How can I solve this problem??

Many thanks!!

Comment: ask this question at serverfault.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I could not find /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock anymore

If you can get a CLI session open on the database, try running "show variables" and look for the variable 'socket'. (try -h 127.0.0.1).

> my mysql server can not run.

eh? Do you mean it has failed to start? That there is no mysqld process? That's different from not being able to find the socket file. Does /var/run/mysqld directory exist? Is it writaeable? What is in your /etc/my.cnf? The script which starts mysqld?